# Is it possible to inject python code in Kwargs and how could I prevent this user input

Tags: python, security, flask, code-injection, keyword-argument

I'm at the moment in the middle of writing my Bachelor thesis and for it creating a database system with Postgres and Flask. 
To ensure the safety of my data, I was working on a file to prevent SQL injections, since a user should be able to submit a string via Http request. Since most of my functions which I use to analyze the Http request use Kwargs and a dict based on JSON in the request I was wondering if it is possible to inject python code into those kwargs. 
And If so If there are ways to prevent that.

To make it easier to understand what I mean, here are some example requests and code:

```
def calc_sum(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c


@app.route(/<target:string>/<value:string>)
def handle_request(target,value):
    if target == 'calc_sum':
        cmd = json.loads(value)
        calc_sum(**cmd)
```

example Request:

```
Normal   : localhost:5000/calc_sum/{"a":1, "b":2}
Injected : localhost:5000/calc_sum/{"a":1, "b:2 ): print("ham") def new_sum(a=1, b=2):return a+b":2 }
```

Since I'm not near my work, where all my code is I'm unable to test it out. And to be honest that my code example would work. But I hope this can convey what I meant.

I hope you can help me, or at least nudge me in the right direction. I've searched for it, but all I can find are tutorials on "who to use kwargs".

Best regards.

Comment: python kwargs are just named values.  There is nothing dangerous about a string that happens to contain malicious code, until you try to `exec` or `eval` that string. `json.loads`, with the default decoder at least, doesn't do anything dangerous. See this documentation page for the lists of types that are used https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you, but not in URL, try to use arguments like these `localhost:5000/calc_sum?func=a+b&a=1&b=2`

and to get these arguments you need to do this in flask

```
@app.route(/<target:string>)
def handle_request(target):
   if target == 'calc_sum':
       func= request.args.get('func')
       a = request.args.get('a')
       b = request.args.get('b')
       result = exec(func)
```

exec is used to execute python code in strings

Comment: Thank you, so as long as I never run exec on the arguments given in the request I'm save?